# Ruby Mysql - Failed to allocate memory error

Tags: mysql, ruby, memory

I have a large MySQL table of about 4 million rows, which I want to process with a ruby script.  At the moment, when I run the script I get a "failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)".  The query runs but the error pops up once I try to loop through the resultset.  Can I allocate more memory to the ruby heap space?

Currently, I am thinking of saving the resultset to a large file and the processing that file in chunks.

Any suggestion on an alternative course of action?

Thanks all,

s

Comment: Do you really need to load all the data into memory? I think you can query the database using SQL's "limit" and "offset" to fetch the data by parts.

Comment: I concur what @venj says. It is very likely that your 4 million rows results in a memory need that's higher than 2 or 3GB, which are usually the limits of memory that can be allocated by a 32-bits process (respectively on Windows without tweaks/hacks and linux).

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I was just thinking,  I'll 40,000 at a time and then work through that.  If you want to stick this as an answer I'll up accept it.